# Converting SQL server date format

Tags: sql, date

[Google Charts Annotated Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline)

According to the above link, while inserting the dates in rows, they have dates added like this

```
new Date(1992, 1, 20)
```

I am not manually adding data but getting data from database on sql server.How do I get dates in this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd pull out the component parts from your SQL Server date field:

```
select datepart(yyyy, yourDateCol), datepart(mm, yourDateCol), datepart(dd, yourDateCol)
from yourTable
```

And then build the component parts of `Date(1992, 1, 20)` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends heavily on the server language you are using, since that's where the logic that does the work of formatting the date happens. sql cannot do logic.

I will provide you an example using php.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

It has a time() function. I'm sure you're language does too. So in php, it would be

```
$today = date("y, m, d");
```